# Python program calling prolog and print prolog output

Tags: python-2.7, prolog, ffi

I'm new using prolog and I have a python program that using os.system(prolog_command) call prolog and get a result (true or false) but I want my program to show in the console the same result (lines that prolog write).
Anyone can help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Exactly what does your `prolog_command` look like? And how is it generating output? Is it providing output via something like, `write` or via variable instantiation?

Comment: Output is generating via write

Comment: What I do in my python program is call prolog using
 shellcommand =  "swipl -q -s init.pl -f "+logicprogram
and then do os.system(shellcommand)

But his only open prolog shell and then I want to write the query to prolog in it with python program but I can't ..

Comment: `os.system(...)` returns the exit code of the command executed, not the standard out. See my answer regarding an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this simple approach:

Contents of `foo.pl`:

```
foo :- write('hello, world'), nl.
```

And then in python:

```
>>> import commands
>>> commands.getoutput('echo "foo." | swipl -q -f foo.pl')
'hello, world\ntrue.\n\n'
>>> x = commands.getoutput('echo "foo." | swipl -q -f foo.pl')
>>> x
'hello, world\ntrue.\n\n'
>>>
```